# Making model INT field nullable disables client side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC 6 project where I had a simple model with various data types (string, int, datetime, etc).

I included the query-validation and jquery.validation.unobtrisive.js files. I add an input for each field using the Html.Editorfor and an Html.Validationmessagefor line. When I add any alpha characters in my int fields or add incorrect date formats and try to submit, I get some nice, near error messages that alert me to the problem and prevents me from submitting the form.

However, if I make an INT field nullable in the model, that validation no longer happens. It lets me submit, the ModelState.Isvalid becomes true and it basically just discards any data that isn't valid which, for a reporting app, can lead to the user getting too much data (not realizing that their filter was discarded) and making decisions based on this extra data that they didn't noticed SHOULDN'T be there.

Is there a way to KEEP this client-size validation happening for nullable int types exactly the way it happens when it's non-nullable? This doesn't seem to be an issue with datetime field that are nullable. Maybe because in the Model I have the option to add a data attribute such as

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
 public Nullable<DateTime> datestart { get; set; }
```

This Datatype enumeration doesnt seem to include a value for integers through, only fields like "datetime, HTML, Email, ImageUrl, etc). Addition an annotation such as the following didn't help either:

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "This must be a positive number")]
```

Comment: Making it nullable does not disable client side validation - it just means you can leave the input blank and it will post back a `null` value. If you enter (say) "ABC" you will still get a client side validation message. If that is not working for you, then it due to something in your code. (as a side note, the `[DataType]` attribute has nothing to do with validation - it just determines the `type` attribute that will be displayed in the `<input>` when using `EditorFor()`

Comment: That's interesting. Because the only change I've made between the validation working and not working was changing the model from int to Nullable<int>. I went back and forth a couple of times adding it and removing it just to make sure that I wasn't crazy and sure enough, this was causing the letters to be allowed client-side in an int field (and then discarded when passed to the controller). I didn't see any JS errors. I'll keep searching, though.

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8TexSa). Leave the textbox empty or enter a valid integer and it will submit without error. But enter say "ABC", and you will get a client side error and the form will not be submitted (note I will delete the fiddle in a few days)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. One thing to note first: For some reason when I booted up my project today and put text in an integer field and tabbed out, the letters disappeared. I swear this didn't happen yesterday and I'm not crazy. That's a good thing so people don't submit text but its also bad because someone could have entered a number and accidentally put a letter and their whole number would then be wiped out. THAT being said: The issue was that I was using EDITORFOR instead of TEXTBOXFOR. EDITORFOR wipes out the value during onblur if invalid. TEXTBOX fires the actual validation instead!

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Muecke's example helped me figure out the issue.

I was using Html.EditorFor instead of Html.TextboxFor.

The former would wipe out invalid text when I tabbed/onblurred causing someone who accidentally put a letter in the field to have their number wiped out, causing people to be angry due to having to retype... or even worse, not realize it got wiped out and submitting a blank value because they weren't paying attention. When i switched to Html.TextBoxFor, it retained the valid, fired the validation error message and prevented the form from submitting which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Using `EditorFor()` is the same as using `TextBoxFor()` except that because the type of `int` it will add `type="number"`, which will generate the browsers numeric control. So what ever behavior you seeing is due to the browser not permitting values that are not numbers.